# Orange mark in device list

Tags: partitioning, gparted, dolphin

When starting my computer some devices are marked with a green sign and some with an orange one:

Device overview from Dolphin 17.04.3 on Ubuntu 17.10:
[image: Device overview from Dolphin 17.04.3 on Ubuntu 17.10]

Where the "Linux Main Partition" denotes the partition the OS is installed on, and "SSD" is a second internal drive of type fat32. I would like to get this drive also directly accessible after a start, which is not possible if it's marked as orange (e.g. links to files stored on this partition do not work directly after the start) How do I change the property of the "SSD" device/partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No official flavor of Ubuntu supports 17.10 anymore. That said, look at `System Settings` > `Removable Devices`. This image is from Kubuntu 18.04:

[image: Removable Devices]

Comment: Great, solved it!